# Hidden cards in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I have created lists on my Trello board and added cards to the list. When I log back in the lists appear and they say '2 cards' or whatever next to the title but I can't actually view the cards!

It's like my lists have closed but I need to open them again so I can actually see the jobs on there.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you've got a filter on.  Click "Filter Cards" in the right sidebar, and then "Clear All Filters".  Alternatively, hit 'x' to clear the filter.

Comment: Doh, thank you very much that was indeed the case!